# How to handle Ctrl+X shortcut keys

Tags: c, winapi

I receive the first message box but not the second one when I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> together. How can I fix this?

```
case WM_KEYDOWN:
    if (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) {
        MessageBox(0, "Ctrl", "Key", 0);
        switch (wParam) {
            case VK_RETURN:
                MessageBox(0, "Enter", "Key", 0);
                break;
        }
    }
    break;
```

Comment: You are meant to handle such keyboard actions with accelerators

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can't mark your answer as accepted here...

Comment: OK, there's an answer for you to accept! I didn't write it as an answer first because I wasn't sure you'd be receptive to an alternative method - not everyone is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than handle low-level keypress events, it is best to handle such keyboard actions with accelerators.

Answer (score 1):

Accelerators are typically used for application-level commands - eg. <kbd>Ctrl-N</kbd> to open a new document. If this key combo is specific to this `HWND` - eg. if it is a control-specific keyboard command, then processing it in the control is the way to go.

My guess as to what's happening in your code is as follows: when you hit Ctrl+Enter, Windows generates two `WM_KEYDOWN` messages; one for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, and one for the ENTER. when you get the one for the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, you display the message box, and now its internal message loop takes over - it's going to get any further input until it is dismissed.

Try dropping the first `MessageBox` (you know you're hitting that point anyhow), and just see if the second one gets hit. Or use some diagnostic output technique (eg `OutputDebugString()`) that's not going to interfere with the input.